# How to send Data in chunks from server (node.js) to client(react.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, sequelize.js, endpoint

I ended up with having a Server who provides pictures in base64 format. The Problem is when I want to send an array of base64 Images they are to huge.

I want to send the Array in little chunks to the frontend. 
I use Sequelize to retrieve the data from the database.

Does someone has an Idea How to do it.

Thats How my endpoint looks until now:

```
router.get('/download', async (req, res, next) => {

    try {
        const getAllStoneData = await StoneData.findAll();

        const convertBlobToString = getAllStoneData.map((oneStone) => {

            const getBuffer = oneStone.dataValues.blobImage;
            const convertToString = getBuffer.toString('utf8');
            const copyOneStone = {
                ...oneStone.dataValues,
                blobImage: convertToString,
            };

            return copyOneStone;
        });

        let chunk = [];
        while (convertBlobToString.length > 0) {
            chunk = convertBlobToString.splice(0, 1);

            res.write(chunk);

        }

        res.end();

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send({ error });
    }
});
```

When I run this I get the Error of

"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Comment: Have you checked whether the error is because of the `catch` block? It tries to send a 400 response, but you’re probably already in the middle of one.

Comment: Yes the error dissappears or is not in the console. I think this is the first step.

I am not even sure if the little function I wrote is suitable in doing so. I found already 

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93/

But still dont understand properly

Comment: When deleting the res.status a timeout appears!

Comment: I suggest adding some logging to see what’s happening when it times out.

Comment: I stopped following this approach, because sending chunks of data makes sense for streaming or very huge data. 
There are Libaries out there like socket.io which supports this kind of feature. No need to implement it by myself.

Maybe for smaller projects which dont want a massive libary like socket.io.

If someone wants to follow this appraoch for smaller Projects I would be interested as well.

However I use now multer in order to just send the link back and not the whole file.